# TinyMCE MySQL and html tags

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

Here's my problem: I am using for the first time TinyMCE for a textarea for data that is inserted into a database to display on a blog.

I type data into the textarea, insert into the database table, and when the text arrives in the database it has html tags. When it displays on the web page it display html tags. The tags are apparently added by TinyMCE, which might be okay if they worked. But they do not work. They only display.

I have searched but cannot find an understandable solution. I tried sanitizing the posted data. I tried removing all filters. Nothing works.

A solution suggested adding this, which I added to the head under the cdn link, but to no avail:

```
    <script>
        tinyMCE.init({
            mode: "textareas",
            theme: "advanced",
            force_br_newlines: false,
            force_p_newlines: false,
            forced_root_block: '',
        });
    </script>
```

If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: The reason moste likely is that you  escape the html code of you post either wen you insert it to your database or when you display it on you webpage.

Comment: @t.niese. Thanks for your reply. Yes, I "sanitize" post data, but in this instance, I removed all filters:  $post_content = $_POST['post_content'];  The content of $post_content is then inserted into the DB table.  In MySQL I see that the content includes html tags. These are then displayed on the web page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following tags when you output data from your database

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($your_custom_variable));
```